# R: Plotting a Combinatorial Function

Tags: r, math

I am working in the R programming language.

**I am trying to make a plot from n=0 to n = 1000 for the following function (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH2kATv49rc&t=7s):**

[image]

First, I tried to define the P_00(2n) part:

```
combinatorial_square <- function(n) {
  (choose(2*n, n)^2) * ((1/4)^(2*n))
}
```

Then, I tried to write another function that performs the cumulative sum of the above function:

```
cumulative_sum <- function(N) {
  s <- 0
  for (n in 1:N) {
    s <- s + (choose(2*n, n)^2) * ((1/4)^(2*n))
  }
  return(s)
}
```

Then, I tried to plot it over a range of N's:

```
N <- 1:250
y <- sapply(N, cumulative_sum)

plot(N, y, type = "l", main = "Plot of cumulative_sum function", xlab = "N", ylab = "cumulative_sum(N)")
```

[image]

**My Problem:** I can not seem to plot this function for larger values of N (I think this might be because the computer is not able to calculate large combinatorial terms?):

```
 N <- 1:1000
    y <- sapply(N, cumulative_sum)

> tail(y)
[1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

**Is there something I can do in R to approximate these larger factorials?**

Currently, I was thinking of using some mathematical method to approximate the larger factorial terms involved in combinatorial expressions (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) - that is, re-write the `cumulative_sum` function so that it uses Stirling Approximation for each factorial term.

But is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got `NAN` since `choose(2*n, n)^2` explodes for large `n`, but you should have way to circumvent that issue for big numbers.

---

You can rearrange the terms in the math expression and make sure that each item is less than 1 and decay in the power law (in your case, it is power of `2`), and then you will make it "converge" (not the same concept of "convergence" in series sum of the math domain), for example

```
f <- Vectorize(function(n) {
  v <- seq_len(n)
  prod((n + v) / (4 * v))^2
})
```

and then run (up to `10000` for exmaple)

```
N <- 1:10000
P <- cumsum(f(N))
plot(N, P,  type = "l", main = "Plot of cumulative_sum function", xlab = "N", ylab = "cumulative_sum(N)")
```

and you will obtain

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to use logarithms. Base R has logarithm versions of the `beta`, `gamma`, `choose` and `factorial` functions. These versions are prefixed with an `l`, are numerically stable and can be invaluable when the numbers become very large. The relevant function is [`lchoose`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Special.html).

First test the functions' results.

```r
combinatorial_square <- function(n) {
  (choose(2*n, n)^2) * ((1/4)^(2*n))
}
cumulative_sum <- function(N) {
  s <- 0
  for (n in 1:N) {
    s <- s + (choose(2*n, n)^2) * ((1/4)^(2*n))
  }
  return(s)
}

lcombinatorial_square <- function(n) {
  2*lchoose(2*n, n) + 2*n * log(1/4)
}

N <- 1:250
y1 <- sapply(N, combinatorial_square)
y2 <- sapply(N, lcombinatorial_square)

# all values are equal to floating-point accuracy
mapply(all.equal, log(y1), y2) |> all()
#> [1] TRUE
mapply(all.equal, y1, exp(y2)) |> all()
#> [1] TRUE

# but only 1% are exactly equal
# (note that the vectors log(y1) and y2 have the same attributes
# therefore the two instructions that follow are equivalent)
mapply(identical, y1, exp(y2)) |> mean()
#> [1] 0.012
mapply(`==`, y1, exp(y2)) |> mean()
#> [1] 0.012

# (note also that if the test is on log(y1) 3% are exactly equal)
mapply(identical, log(y1), y2) |> mean()
#> [1] 0.028
mapply(`==`, log(y1), y2) |> mean()
#> [1] 0.028

# now test with larger numbers
N <- 1:1000
y2 <- sapply(N, lcombinatorial_square)
y2 |> exp() |> is.finite() |> all()
#> [1] TRUE
y2 |> exp() |> max()
#> [1] 0.25
y2 |> exp() |> sum()
#> [1] 2.265321
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Finally, compute the sums with bigger `N` and plot the summation.

```r
lcombinatorial_square <- function(n) 2*lchoose(2*n, n) + 2*n * log(1/4)

# cumulative_sum_2a <- function(N) {
#   s <- 0
#   for (n in seq.int(N)) {
#     e <- exp(lcombinatorial_square(n))
#     s <- s + e
#   }
#   s
# }

cumulative_sum_2 <- function(N) {
  N |> 
    seq.int() |>
    sapply(lcombinatorial_square) |> 
    exp() |> 
    sum()
}

N <- 1:1000
y <- sapply(N, cumulative_sum_2)
plot(N, y, type = "l", main = "Plot of cumulative_sum function", 
     xlab = "N", ylab = "cumulative_sum(N)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `lchoose` plays the magic, cool! +1!